# How to define rand() according to probability?

Tags: c, random, posix, probability, ansi-c

I have one bag with three equal balls. I made code to simulate the number of times each ball comes off (it works flawlessly so far).

#### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 50 /* Number of simulations*/
#define P 3  /* Number of of balls*/

unsigned long long millitime2(){
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return (unsigned long long)(tv.tv_usec);
}

int main() {
    int i;
    int num = 0;
    int *v;
    if((v = malloc(N*sizeof(int))) == NULL){
        printf("\n\tMEMORY ERROR");
        exit(1);
    }
    memset(v,0,N);
    printf("\nexpected freq: %f\n\n", ((float)1/(float)P)*100);

    for (i=0; i<N; i++){
        srand(millitime2());
        num = (rand()%P);
        v[num]++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<P;i++){
        printf("ball:%d   picked:%d/%d   freq:%f\n",i+1,v[i],N,((float)v[i]/(float)N)*100);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

But now the study I'm doing requires that from three balls; one ball is blue and two balls are white.

What do I have to change in the line with `rand()`, so it spits a blue ball one out of three times (~33%) and a white ball two out of three times(~66%)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int x = rand() % 3;
```

x will choose a 'random' number between 0 and 2

if x <= 1 then white ( 66%)
if x == 2 then blue ( 33%)

Comment: `x = rand() % 3;` will give `x` with 33.3% probability all the time, or am i wrong ?? **how about when there are 10 balls 3 blue 3 white and 4 black** ???

Comment: Then use `x = rand() % 10`. If x < 3 means blue, else x < 6 means white, otherwise black.

Comment: **"10 balls 3 blue 3 white and 4 black"** ??

  x<3 blue ; 3<=x<7 white ; x>=7 black  ???

Answer (score 1):

make your own function

```
#define BLUE 1
#define WHITE 2

int whichBall()
{
  int val = rand() % P;
  if (val == 0)
    return BLUE;
  return WHITE;
}
```

this will return BLUE 33% of the time and WHITE 66% of the time

for 10 balls 3 blue 3 white and 4 black do:

```
#define BLUE = 3
#define WHITE = 3
#define BLACK = 4

int whichBall()
{
  int val = rand() % P;
  if (val < BLUE)
    return BLUE;
  if (val < BLUE + WHITE)
    return WHITE;
  if (val < BLUE + WHITE + BLACK)
    return BLACK
  return BLACK;//This line should never be reached but is included so it compiles
}
```

Comment: please help me understand the logic behind it, i think `val = rand() % P;` will give `val` with 33.3% probability all the time, **+ the hard part comes when there are 10 balls 3 blue 3 white and 4 black**

Comment: @mf_ I've edited in a solution to that, hopefully you can see the pattern quite easily

Comment: Also, someone will eventually point out that this method won't produce numbers with exactly equal probabilities, but they're probably close enough for a simple exercise. Also, take `srand()` outside of your loop; it's probably causing you to get the same number many times.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround for this is:

- Imagine having a bag with 10 balls, 3 red, 3 blue, 3 green, and 1 white.
- Get an array[10].
- Fill [0][1][2] with 'red', [3][4][5] with 'blue', [6][7][8] with 'green' and [9] 'white'.
- Call rand()%10 = **index** of array.
- You will get approximately 30% red, 30% blue, 30% green and 10% white.